# Get the name of user who created the event on shared secondary calendar

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a mailbox that has a secondary calendar. That calendar is shared with a user withing the organization with Permissions to  create item/edit items but not delete. Need to get the name of user created or last modified a event
I am using Graph API to retrieve an event from that calendar with the name of the user who created or last modified that event. I am getting the token using Client Credentials.
So far, I am getting IsOrganizer=true if the owner creates that event or the person who this calendar is shared with creates it.

Is there a way to identify who created the event on the shared calendar?

I am using Graph API to retrieve an event from that calendar with the name of the user who created or last modified that event. I am getting the token using Client Credentials.
So far, I am getting IsOrganizer=true if the owner creates that event or the person who this calendar is shared with creates it.

I have tried to retrieve certain values using the SingleValueExtendedProperties found in the Master property list MX-OXPROPS document but no luck.

Is there a way to identify who created the event on the shared calendar?

Comment: If you look at the appointment with MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage button), do you see the relevant creator/modifier properties?

Comment: I did try it with MFCMAPI but I don't see any field that shows the name of the creator.

Comment: Do you see the creator entry id?